# Loop through columns, then transform cells, then show unique values in awk

Tags: awk

I'd like to transform some data using awk but need some help pls. I want to extract for columns starting with "sam" (where the column number is undefined) everything before the first colon.

Input:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    sam1    sam2    sam3
a   b   c   d   0/1:12  1/0:9   0/1:16
e   f   g   h   0/0:7   1/1:98  0/0:8
```

Desired output:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    sam1    sam2    sam3
a   b   c   d   0/1 1/0 0/1
e   f   g   h   0/0 1/1 0/0
```

This is the best I've got so far... but it doesn't work.

```
awk -F"\t" '{ for(i=5; i<=NF; --i); split($i,a,":"); print a[1]}}' input > output
```

I know how to cut a column i.e. `cut -d ':' -f2` but as far as I understand you can't combine cut with awk in a loop!

Then, I want to find all the unique values for columns starting with sam in the output file e.g.

```
0/1
1/0
0/0
1/1
```

I'm afraid I'm totally lost on an awk solution for that. I can do it in R but an awk solution would be preferred and much faster.

R solution:

```
output %>% pivot_longer(-c(col1:col4)) -> df_long
df_long %<>% select(value)
unique(df_long)
```

Comment: You just need to gsub $i then print $0. If your column locations vary, you also detect the column numbers in `NR == 1 {}` and store them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in one go fairly easily. For example simply using `gsub()` to remove the `:XX` from each field and then a simple array to collect the unique `sam` fields you would have:

```bash
awk -F"\t" '{gsub(/:[^[:space:]]+/,"")} FNR>1 {for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]++} END {for (i in a) print i}1' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your content in `file` you would have:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '{gsub(/:[^[:space:]]+/,"")} FNR>1 {for (i=5; i<=NF; i++) a[$i]++} END {for (i in a) print i}1' file
col1    col2    col3    col4    sam1    sam2    sam3
a       b       c       d       0/1     1/0     0/1
e       f       g       h       0/0     1/1     0/0
1/0
1/1
0/0
0/1
```

---

**In Awk Script Form**

You can put the contents in a simple script file and make it executable with `chmod +x` and then just provide the filename to read as an argument. For example, create `sam.awk` as follows:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
{
  gsub(/:[^[:space:]]+/,"")
  print
}
FNR>1 {
  for (i=5; i<=NF; i++)
    a[$i]++
}
END {
  for (i in a)
    print i
}
```

Now simply `chmod +x sam.awk` and execute `./sam.awk file` to produce:

```
$ ./sam.awk file
col1    col2    col3    col4    sam1    sam2    sam3
a       b       c       d       0/1     1/0     0/1
e       f       g       h       0/0     1/1     0/0
1/0
1/1
0/0
0/1
```

Either way, as a one-liner or as a script is fine -- up to you entirely.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^sam/) cols[i]} 
             {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                if(i in cols) 
                  {split($i,t,":"); $i=t[1]}}1' file | 
  column -t

col1  col2  col3  col4  sam1  sam2  sam3
a     b     c     d     0/1   1/0   0/1
e     f     g     h     0/0   1/1   0/0
```

or just interested in the unique values

```
$ awk 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^sam/) cols[i]; next} 
             {for(i in cols) {split($i,t,":"); if(!vals[t[1]]++) print t[1]}}' file

0/1
1/0
0/0
1/1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
    NR==1 { while(i++<NF) if ($i ~ /^sam/) p[i] }
    NR>1 { for (i in p) { sub(/:.*$/,"",$i); u[$i] } }
    { print >"output" }
    END { for (i in u) print i >"unique" }
' input
```

- use first row to populate a list with columns of interest
- on subsequent rows, process relevant columns and copy amended values to hash
- print each line to the file called "output"
- at the end print the keys of the hash to a file called "unique"

awk's arrays are hashes so storing items as keys of an array gives the unique items

Answer (score 0):

*"find all the unique values for columns starting with sam"*

```
$ grep -o "[0-9]/[0-9]" inputfile|sort -u
0/0
0/1
1/0
1/1
```